# Drawing in MvxTableViewCell

Tags: xamarin.ios, drawing, xamarin, mvvmcross

I would like to draw a rectangle in every tablevievcell of my MvxTableViewController.
I have a custom cellLabel extending UIView

```cs
namespace Next.Client.Application.iOS.Views.UI
{
    [Register("CellLabel")]
    public class CellLabel : UIView
    {
        public CellLabel()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public CellLabel(RectangleF bounds)
            : base(bounds)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        }

        public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);

            //get graphics context
            using (CGContext gc = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
            {
                //set up drawing attributes
                gc.SetLineWidth(1);
                UIColor.Blue.SetFill();
                UIColor.Red.SetStroke();

                //create geometry
                var path = new CGPath();

                path.AddLines(new PointF[]{
                        new PointF (0, 45),
                        new PointF (80, 45), 
                        new PointF (90, 50), 
                        new PointF (0, 50)
                });

                path.CloseSubpath();

                //add geometry to graphics context and draw it
                gc.AddPath(path);
                gc.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a custom cell where to draw in

```cs
namespace Next.Client.Application.iOS
{
    public partial class ObservationCell : MvxTableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName ("ObservationCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("ObservationCell");

        private CellLabel _labelView;

        public ObservationCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            _labelView = new CellLabel();
            this.AddSubview(_labelView);

            this.DelayBind(() => {
                var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ObservationCell, Observation>();
                set.Bind(MainLbl).To(observation => observation.BrutText);
                set.Bind(SubLeftLbl).To(observation => observation.Praticien.Personne.DisplayFullName);
                set.Bind(SubRightLbl).To(observation => observation.DateTimeHumanShort);
                set.Apply();
            });
        }

        public static ObservationCell Create ()
        {
            return (ObservationCell)Nib.Instantiate (null, null) [0];
        }
    }
}
```

but nothing show up :/
any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CellLabel doesn't currently seem to have any Frame - so it's probably being drawn inside (0,0,0,0)

Try:

```
        _labelView = new CellLabel(new RectangleF(0,0,320,100));
        this.AddSubview(_labelView);
```

---

If you add a `CellLabel(IntPtr)` constructor, then you can also use the CellLabel as a type in the XIB editor - it won't fully draw within the editor, but the editor will allow you to specify it as the type and it will get correctly loaded at runtime.

---

One final note... I don't think I'd call it a Label - could be confusing to people who read the code later.